# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: not called because array is empty?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, strongly-typed-dataset, weak-references

My tableView wasn't loading because `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` wasn't being called. The `NSLog` messages that I have written inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` did not appear in the console. I had a `weak` NSArray @property called listOfItems. When I changed it to `strong`, the tableView finally showed it's contents. Could someone please clarify if `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` wasn't being called because the NSArray was weak. Is there a connection between the `listOfItems` property and the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method being called?

Comment: can you post the ``numberOfSectionsInTableView:`` method?

Comment: I think you mean numberOfRows, and even so, that would be irrelevant.

Comment: can you post it for me? i want to know how are you doing the ``numberOfRowsInTableView`` because i have the same problem once and the error was int ``numberOfRowsInTableView``

Answer (score 3):

No object had a strong reference to the array. Your view controller had a reference, but it wasn't strong. This means that you don't care if it gets removed from memory, you don't need it to stick around. In this case, since your table relied on the data in the array, you don't want it to be removed from memory: you want it to stay around as long as the table stays around. To do so, you create a strong reference, which makes sure that that object isn't being removed from memory *until* that pointer (your property, in this case) didn't point to it anymore.